# how to quickly create ElasticSearch2.0 mapping with hundreds fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Previously I was using ES 1.5, so I could very easily create hundreds hierachy mapping as following:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "country.*.population": {
      "type": "int"
    }
  }
}
```

That means there are hundreds countries under parent filed country with type int.

Right now since ES2.0 doesn't support dot in field name, so I have to write hundred times mapping when I creating the mapping. for example:

```
{
  "country": {
    "properties": {
      "usa": {
        "properties": {
          "population": {
            "type": "int"
          }
        }
      },
      "canada": {
        "properties": {
          "population": {
            "type": "int"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas about this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [dynamic template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) in your mapping, like this:

```
PUT index
{
  "mappings": {
    "type": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "countries": {
            "path_match":   "country.*.population",
            "mapping": {
              "type":       "int"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: oh, too tired, even forgot the solution I ever used :-)